# BeautifulSoup cannot be used

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python 3.6, and have installed beautifulsoup4 using pip install beautifulsoup4. But if I typed from bs4 import BeautifulSoup in Python3 environment, I get the following Trackback. I've updated beautifulsoup and html5 as some similar posts suggested, but haven't solved the problem.

```
{'results': [], 'status': 'ZERO_RESULTS'}
AttributeError: module 'copy' has no attribute 'deepcopy'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "part.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/builder/__init__.py", line 323, in <module>
    from . import _html5lib
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/builder/_html5lib.py", line 20, in <module>
    import html5lib
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/html5lib/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .html5parser import HTMLParser, parse, parseFragment
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/html5lib/html5parser.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import inputstream
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/html5lib/inputstream.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/html5lib/utils.py", line 8, in <module>
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as default_etree
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/cElementTree.py", line 3, in <module>
    from xml.etree.ElementTree import *
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1654, in <module>
    from _elementtree import *
  SystemError: <built-in function __import__> returned a result with an error set
```

Comment: This looks like a pretty standard import error to me. Do you perhaps have something in your PATH (or PYTHONPATH) that's shadowing the stdlib `copy` module?

Comment: ^Can you elaborate?

Comment: I think a custom module (something you've written, perhaps) named `copy.py` is in python's import path and so when `bs4` tries to use `copy.deepcopy` (from the stdlib), it can't find it.

Comment: from an interpreter, do `import copy` then `copy.__file__`. If it's somewhere other than Python's lib folder, that's your problem!

Comment: You are totally right! I would never figured that out myself. Problem solved! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think a custom module maybe something you've written named `copy.py` is in python's import path and so when `bs4` tries to use `copy.deepcopy` from the `stdlib`, it can't find it.

from an interpreter, do :

```
import copy
```

then :

```
copy.__file__.
```

If it's somewhere other than Python's lib folder, that's your problem!